# Задать точку вращения(Origin) для VertexArray sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Как задать точку вращения(Origin) для массива векторов (VertexArray)?
Для фигуры я могу просто написать `figure.setOrigin()`. Но как сделать подобное для массива векторов?

Comment: Задать матрицу rotation * offset и перемножать с ней координаты вершин в вершинном шейдере.

Comment: @user7860670,  в SFML не обязательно лезть в шейдеры, там есть класс `sf::Matrix3` и у него есть функция `Vector2f sf::Matrix3::Transform (const Vector2f& Point) ` через которую надо прогнать все точки массива

Comment: @PavelGridin Это будет прокатывать только пока точек не очень много или изменяются они не особо часто. Так что имеет смысл все сразу по-максимому переносить на GPU.

Comment: @user7860670, это понятно, но довольно сложно для начинающих